# insert date in wrong way

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

im trying to insert into table date in this type dd/mm/yyyy.
in the mysql i set the data type to DATE.
when i click add and insert the date this error is shown.
"mysql.data.types.mysqlconversionexpection {"Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime"}"

i cant find the mistake.
thanks alot!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class usageDisp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionstring = @"Data Source=localhost; Database=globaldotdb; user ID=root; Password=peleg1708";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //check
                BindData();

            }
        }
        private void BindData()
        {         
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT  tblusage.codeUsage,tblcustom.Customer, tblvendor.Vendor, tblusage.dateStart, tblusage.dateEnd, tblregion.Region, tblservice.Service, tblservice.unit, tblusage.isSecure,tblusage.Usages FROM     ((((tblvendor INNER JOIN tblusage ON tblvendor.codeVendor = tblusage.codeVendor) INNER JOIN  tblservice ON tblusage.codeService = tblservice.codeService) INNER JOIN  tblregion ON tblusage.codeRegion = tblregion.codeRegion) INNER JOIN  tblcustom ON tblusage.codeCust = tblcustom.codeCust)"), cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gv.DataSource = dt;
                    gv.DataBind();



                }
            }
        }

        protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int codeusage = int.Parse(gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

            deleteusage(codeusage);
            BindData();
        }

        private void deleteusage(int codeusage)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM tblusage WHERE codeUsage=" + codeusage + " ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

        protected void gv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList DDLCu = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLCu") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLVe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLVe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLSe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLSe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLRe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLRe") as DropDownList;


            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter Cadp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblcustom"), cn);
                DataTable Cdt = new DataTable();
                Cadp.Fill(Cdt);
                if (Cdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLCu.DataSource = Cdt;
                    DDLCu.DataTextField = "Customer";
                    DDLCu.DataValueField = "codeCust";
                    DDLCu.DataBind();

                }


                MySqlDataAdapter Vadp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblvendor"), cn);
                DataTable Vdt = new DataTable();
                Vadp.Fill(Vdt);
                if (Vdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLVe.DataSource = Vdt;
                    DDLVe.DataTextField = "Vendor";
                    DDLVe.DataValueField = "codeVendor";
                    DDLVe.DataBind();

                }


                MySqlDataAdapter Sadp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblservice"), cn);
                DataTable Sdt = new DataTable();
                Sadp.Fill(Sdt);
                if (Sdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLSe.DataSource = Sdt;
                    DDLSe.DataTextField = "Service";
                    DDLSe.DataValueField = "codeService";
                    DDLSe.DataBind();

                }


                MySqlDataAdapter Radp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblregion"), cn);
                DataTable Rdt = new DataTable();
                Radp.Fill(Rdt);
                if (Rdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLRe.DataSource = Rdt;
                    DDLRe.DataTextField = "Region";
                    DDLRe.DataValueField = "codeRegion";
                    DDLRe.DataBind();

                }
            }

        }

        protected void lnkAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList DDLCu = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLCu") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLVe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLVe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLSe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLSe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLRe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLRe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLIS = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLIS") as DropDownList;
            TextBox txtds = (TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("TBDS");
            TextBox txtde = (TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("TBDE");
           TextBox txtus = (TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxUnit");
            int usage = int.Parse(txtus.Text);
            int cc = int.Parse(DDLCu.SelectedValue);
            int cv = int.Parse(DDLVe.SelectedValue);
            int cs = int.Parse(DDLSe.SelectedValue);
            int cr = int.Parse(DDLRe.SelectedValue);
            int iss = int.Parse(DDLIS.SelectedValue);
            string DS = txtds.Text;
            string DE = txtde.Text;


            add(cc, cv, cs, cr, usage, iss, DE, DS);
            BindData();
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:56717/usageDisp.aspx");

        }

        private void add(int cc, int cv, int cs, int cr,int usag,int isecure, string ds, string de)

        {

            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                string query = "insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,Usages,isSecure,dateStart,dateEnd) values (" + cc + "," + cv + "," + cs + "," + cr + "," + usag + "," + isecure + "," + ds + "," + de + ") ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

        protected void CalendarStart_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtds = (TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("TBDS");
            Calendar cas = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("CalendarStart") as Calendar;
            txtds.Text = cas.SelectedDate.ToString("d");

        }

        protected void CalendarEnd_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtde = (TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("TBDE");
            Calendar cas = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("CalendarEnd") as Calendar;
            txtde.Text = cas.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
        }




    }
}



<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="usageDisp.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.usageDisp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="usageDisp" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="codeUsage" 
        onrowdeleting="gv_RowDeleting" 
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="codeusage" Visible="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeUsage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeUsage") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTCust" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCu" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Vendor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLVe" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Vendor") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateStart">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTDS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateStart") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="CalendarStart" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
                    BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#663399" Height="108px" 
                    ShowGridLines="True" Width="132px" 
                    onselectionchanged="CalendarStart_SelectionChanged">
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" Height="1px" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" 
                        ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:Calendar>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TBDS" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateStart") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateEnd">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTDE" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateEnd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="CalendarEnd" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" 
                    DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
                    ForeColor="#003399" Height="108px" Width="132px" 
                    onselectionchanged="CalendarEnd_SelectionChanged">
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" 
                        Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Height="25px" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
                </asp:Calendar>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TBDE" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateEnd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="service">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTSe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSe" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="region">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTRe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLRe" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="isSecure">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTIS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isSecure") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLIS" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">true</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">false</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isSecure") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTunit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unit") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="usage">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTusage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usages") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUnit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" onclick="lnkAdd_Click">add</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usages") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Operation" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can overide the way a date is formatted in MySQL.  You can format it for user-friendliness when you call it back.  But how it's stored is how it's stored.

Comment: Using string concatenation: invitation to SQL Injection attacks. Once switched to parameters, you can just pass a `DateTime` instance without any need to work out which date layout, the database driver handles it.

Comment: MySQL provides many functions for date formatting. `str_to_date`  will resolve your problem. Check it out at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46d5b/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add `Convert.ToDateTime()` , then your query'll definately work.

but, your doing it in a wrong way.
use [Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx),

> A parameterized query is a query in which placeholders are used for
>   parameters and the parameter values are supplied at execution time.
>   The most important reason to use parameterized queries is to avoid [SQL
>   injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

In your case, you need to change the insert query:

```
string query = "insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,Usages,isSecure,dateStart,dateEnd) values (" + cc + "," + cv + "," + cs + "," + cr + "," + usag + "," + isecure + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(ds) + "," + Convert.ToDateTime(de) + ") ";
```

Or, You can change the `ds` and `dt` variable datatype

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format="dd/mm/yyyy";//define your datetime format here

DateTime ds=DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.Text, format, provider);
DateTime de=DateTime.ParseExact(textbox2.Text, format, provider);
```

and then pass it to the query,like

```
 string query = "insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,Usages,isSecure,dateStart,dateEnd) values (" + cc + "," + cv + "," + cs + "," + cr + "," + usag + "," + isecure + "," +ds + "," + de + ") ";
```

Edit 2:

```
 private void add(int cc, int cv, int cs, int cr,int usag,int isecure, string ds, string de)

        {

            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                string query = "insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,Usages,isSecure,dateStart,dateEnd) values (@cc,@cv,@cs,@cr,@usag,@isecure,@ds,@de) ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);

                cmd .Parameters.Add("@cc",MySqlDbType.Int).Value=cc;
                cmd .Parameters.Add("@cv",MySqlDbType.Int).Value=cv;
                cmd .Parameters.Add("@cs",MySqlDbType.Int).Value=cs;
                cmd .Parameters.Add("@cr",MySqlDbType.Int).Value=cr;
                cmd .Parameters.Add("@usag",MySqlDbType.Int).Value=usag;
              cmd .Parameters.Add("@isecure",MySqlDbType.Int).Value=isecure;
                cmd .Parameters.Add("@ds",MySqlDbType.Date).Value=ds;
                cmd .Parameters.Add("@de",MySqlDbType.Date).Value=de;

                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the correct datatype on mysql for the dates?
because when it sets to DATE it shown me this error system.formatexpection.
thanks

Comment: can you try this, `ds.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`; @DR.P

Comment: it gives me this errors "Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider"

"Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments "

on my sql workbench what is the correct datatype for the dates after i convert them to datetime?
thanks.

Comment: yes, first you need to convert to datetime,
`DateTime ds=DateTime.PasreExact(text1,format,sender)` an then need to use in query like `ds.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: i convert them but DATE is not good datatype.
 i dont know ,wich datatypes are good for them?

Comment: Date is ok, no problem with that, but whats the error you are getting now??

Comment: doesnt find CultureInfo.

Comment: add this namespace `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`

Comment: this error show "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' is a type not a namespace " 
i feel hopeless.

Comment: sorry, my bad..
use namespace `System.Globalization`
or you can use `CultureInfo` directly like this
 `System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`

Comment: i did it directly, but it gives this error
"MySql.Data.Types.mysqlconversionexpection   Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime"
this is the code:
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            string format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
            DateTime ds = DateTime.ParseExact(txtds.Text, format, provider);
            DateTime de = DateTime.ParseExact(txtde.Text, format, provider);
            
 add(cc, cv, cs, cr, usage, iss, ds, de);

and i changed it to datetime in the head of the function "add";

Comment: it looks good but i get this error.
"'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType' does not contain a definition for 'Int'"

Comment: i'm not familiar with MySql, You have to format it, i think MySql Contain Integer in place of Int.
so, do some try.

Comment: i success i need to be Int32.
but i have a problem with the dates when i try to insert dates 
i get this error "mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlexception {"Incorrect date value: '0015-09-2015' for column 'dateStart' at row 1"} "
do you have an idea what is the problem?

 Sorry for the many questions

Comment: how you are getting `0015-09-2015` for date?? it's invalid for date.

Comment: i write the code excatly in the way that you tell me. but i think it converts the dates in wrong way.  the correct  is yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: i can't understand why it's `0015-09-2015`.

Comment: never mind finally i add this line Convert.ToDateTime(txtde.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
and i success! 
thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using parametric queries & Convert.toDateTime().

```
private void add(int cc, int cv, int cs, int cr,int usag,int isecure, string ds, string de)

        {
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
             using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand())
             {
               sqlcmd.Connection = cn;
               sqlcmd.CommandText = "insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,Usages,isSecure,dateStart,dateEnd) values (@codeCust,
        @codeVendor, @codeService, @codeRegion, @Usages, @isSecure, @dateStart, @dateEnd)")

               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeCust", cc);
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeVendor", cv);
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeService", cs);
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeRegion", cr);
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usages", usag);
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isSecure", isecure);
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateStart", Convert.ToDateTime(ds));
               sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateEnd", Convert.ToDateTime(de));
               cn.open();
               sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
             }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify date format.

Sample code:

```
str_to_date(de,"%d/%m/%Y")
```

`str_to_date` is mysql function. Kindly refer MySQL documentation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Verify at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46d5b/1

Comment: this is not php, Asp.net..
so, how come `str_to_date`??

Comment: @Ajmot : `str_to_date` is mysql function. Kindly refer MySQL documentation.

Comment: This to all person who have down-voted. Test your knowledge at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46d5b/1

Comment: OK, so `str_to_date` is MySql function, you should have mention it.